# Not everyone has the libraries needed for my program to run

Tags: windows, executable, libraries

So I made this executable program that uses the Windows library and some others (string, ctime, lmcons...) in C++. When it runs on my computer it works great but when I transfer the executable to a computer that does not have some of those libraries on it the program does not run. How do I "add" those libraries in with my code?

Comment: If the libraries are .dll then the executable needs those files to run, so you could put them in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Alternatively, if you change the build configuration to use static libraries, the executable will be larger but will run by itself.

Comment: Is that just a setting in the IDE? I read something about changing the dependencies settings. If I add the names of the desired libraries to the dependencies will they be incorporated as static libraries?

Comment: Also, I looked in some of files for programs that I have on my computer. It looked like they didn't have any of the standard libraries as dlls, only custom ones. However, their .exe files were fairly large, so is it convention to incorporate the standard libraries as static and only custom libraries as dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You need to identify libraries that need to exist on the system in order to execute your application.

2 - you need to create a package that contain these libraries. It could be an installation or a zip file. Depending on the libraries, sometimes they need to be registered on the system, sometimes just dropped in. If you use install packaging software, you can set up registration [if needed]. If you distribute zip or ftp folder, you may need to supply script file. Sometimes libraries are part of some Microsoft package and this package can be prerequisite to run your application. You may pack it into your installation and have it installed silently. There are many ways as you see.

3 - this is up to you how you want to distribute your application and supporting libraries. But best is when user doesn't have to jump the hoops trying to install your stuff. User should click and forget.

Comment: OK, so would I need to download a copy of the library and then include it in a file that the user would get when they downloaded my "package?" And if I did do this, would I need to modify my code to reference the library in some alternate directory or would the standard "include<library.h>" still work? I guess I'm unclear about where the libraries are normally stored and how the IDE/compiler/executable access them.

Comment: Yes, include all necessary libraries. If possible, place all your libraries in one `bin` folder and reference from there.